# How do i use pagination pagination in django when i apply filters in class based view. the url always keeps changing how can i track the url

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views, django-pagination

How do I use pagination in Django when I apply filters in a class-based view. the URL always keeps changing how can I track the URL to go to the next page. can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use django rest framework inbuilt pagination classes.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Personally I use [PageNumberPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination) . The result also returns the link of the next and previous pages along with the total count.

[image: PageNumberPagination response example]

Alternatively, you can use [LimitOffsetPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#limitoffsetpagination). This one is more flexible as compared to PageNumberPagination because the offset and limit can be manipulated from the URL. This is more suitable to the case when the front end has a feature to change the page size.

[image]